# How to write a multiline text in a static text control in mfc?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a simple problem with my static text control. I want to write two sentences in two lines.

I searched everywhere, they answered that its style should not be simple and it should be big enough and then it can be done with \n or \r\n. Another guy wrote that it worked!

I did that, but it's not working! The caption is "Welcome to Genetic Algorithm Simulator Application.\nPlease Choose a Function:"
but it just ignores \n and shows this:
Welcome to Genetic Algorithm Simulator Application.Please Choose a Function:"

Comment: No wrap false and \r\n should work.

Comment: I tried that too, I tried everything actually except Center Image Property! I set that to false and then it worked!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Also keep in mind that if the "Center Image" style (SS_CENTERIMAGE) is applied (giving you vertical centering of the text), then "\r\n" character sequences are ignored.

Answer (score 3):

You should not set SS_SIMPLE style for static control. This is what is causing control to display only single line ignoring new line character. Get rid of this style and it will work.

Comment: Thanks JohnCz for answering, but I did that, I set simple property to false!nothing happened!

Answer (score 2):

center image/no wrap/simple all these three options should set to be false!

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with MFC in VS2008, in the static text control properties set the property "No Wrap" to False and the text should be automatically wrapped to the size of the control.

Comment: Thanks Jeeva for answering, but I tried that too. It's not working!

Comment: @SamanHakimzadeh: Did you tried setting the text in run-time or in properties? Which version of visual studio you are using.

Comment: In properties.I figured it out, the problem was Center Image Property! that was the only property I didn't set to false!

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the style `SS_EDITCONTROL`.